# Create simple text string from array typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some array of strings like this

```
const doc = ['TEST', 'TEST1','TEST2']
```

What I need is to make function that I will create simple string from doc, that will have some different text.

1. If there is just one array member to show

   **const text = 'There is 1 doc TEST1';**
2. If there is two array member to show

   **const text = 'There is doc TEST1 and TEST2';**
3. If there is more than twoarray member to show, of course this doc array can have more than 3 array members, but this is just example

   **const text = 'There is doc TEST1, TEST2 and TEST3';**

Thanks in advance I don't know how even to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toSentence(arr){
  if(arr.length===1)return `There is 1 doc ${arr[0]}`;
  const last = arr.pop();
  const others=arr.join(", ");
  return `There are docs ${others} and ${last}`
}
```

Comment: Problem if there is no array members?

Comment: Put `if(arr.length===0)return 'There are no docs';` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` for all but the last entry, and add the last entry with "and". I suppose for an empty array you would return something like "there is no doc":

```js
function makePhrase(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) return "There is no doc";
    if (arr.length === 1) return "There is 1 doc " + arr;
    return "There is doc " +
        arr.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + " and " + arr.at(-1);
}

console.log(makePhrase([]));
console.log(makePhrase(["test1"]));
console.log(makePhrase(["test1", "test2"]));
console.log(makePhrase(["test1", "test2", "test3"]));
console.log(makePhrase(["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to split this into two functions:

- One for serializing the list, and
- One for forming the statement

> Tip: use the [serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) to reduce ambiguity in your sentences.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKYCcYEMA2MBeqAMjMlIgBR5kBcKUmYA5gNoC6AlHWY04gN4BYAFCIUAdxhQIAC0rUoAOhypmUGRwEixYiFjSIADHXSooIdEgDkVgNzadegwEYTZi0gUtDbe6Mf6qIgATG7mlogABgAk-F4+AL6IWGAAJoixXs5sCZF+OoipqMBYIDhQdEL+BSrkpshl5AC8iDb5BYjAcOiUEAhkiCwwaagAHgA09OhsiHDAiAqKqgwwqMgUHJpVHTr1jYgA1C3DRaOITRcLpEoqanIAtIjOiAD8USnpsTy5iHQx-N9JnkHAUEiDdu4Intyu0xGD-PD4SJQJBYAhksgAMrLVQQIJUa7cFbMdhcKbDPjbRB9MADACOIBSsCgAE9zlcyMpVEx1OdLoZXq1EGA4FZfhybtzeRcWs83mLnGK6G0HKZwkhIgAVGQYIKkWIMplSFlJVJwCCZa5cu6IAB8RkFYqVrSsCS+GGweEIJDIBLIHFyfiRwhpyDgKmUcCYFDQmFwBGI1wopI4tkQAHp04gAETZkSh8OoSPR2OehM+qDJqwAeTAqCsnFTGaz2drqDzIf6heLMY98e9SZYNbrVkmVk14lFjbTmZzbeSaUQE7gHYLEZwUd7ca9id9Q7bo9ay8P45kpnr0+bc7rk2Xkw+S7PqHb+a7683pf7u8r+5HY+P-5PvWY4AGJwBYDabDOLZtrek63kB96LmBFgdq+tLdhu0b6NiYBQLiqDJpes7ZtquqIKQwpwIU5qrm+RZYRQOE4pAhG-heUFXqROqmBRyBPDRECIG2dEYe+2FYixeJVge-6TpBTYkWRvGUWaQnzg+y6iWG4lMZJeEETJf5HvJgHngp0E5sper8Wpwk3ku8ELuk2rntpmGbsxBmsUZwEmaKZnPieKHoBZXHWXxgn2agcFwAh55IekIUdkAA)

```ts
function serializeList (list: string[]): string {
  switch (list.length) {
    case 0: return '';
    case 1: return list[0];
    case 2: return `${list[0]} and ${list[1]}`;
    default: {
      let result = '';
      for (const [index, str] of list.entries()) {
        result += index === list.length - 1 ? `and ${str}` : `${str}, `;
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
}

function asSentence (list: string[]): string {
  const quantity = list.length === 0 ? ' no' : list.length === 1 ? ' 1' : '';
  return `There is${quantity} doc${list.length > 0 ? ' ' : ''}${serializeList(list)}`;
}

console.log(serializeList([])); // ""
console.log(serializeList(['One'])); // "One"
console.log(serializeList(['One', 'Two'])); // "One and Two"
console.log(serializeList(['One', 'Two', 'Three'])); // "One, Two, and Three"
console.log(serializeList(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])); // "One, Two, Three, and Four"

console.log(asSentence([])); // "There is no doc"
console.log(asSentence(['One'])); // "There is 1 doc One"
console.log(asSentence(['One', 'Two'])); // "There is doc One and Two"
console.log(asSentence(['One', 'Two', 'Three'])); // "There is doc One, Two, and Three"
console.log(asSentence(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])); // "There is doc One, Two, Three, and Four"
```